# Exclude all records that meet certain criteria using Excel Advanced Filter

Tags: excel

i have an excel spreadsheet that is as follows

```
ID  drug        dose
1   lisinopril  od
2   ramiipril   bd
2   amlodipine  od
3   lisinopril  od
3   amlodipine  od
4   ramiipril   bd
4   lisinopril  tds
5   amlodipine  od
5   ramiipril   bd
```

Im looking to use advanced filter on the list to just show patients who are only on drugs that have a dose of od.

i.e. my answer should be

```
id drug       dose
1  lisinopril od
3  lisinopril od
3  amlodipine od
```

i just can't get my head around the logic?
any ideas?

-im sorry if my question wasnt clear enough.
my computer system at work (hospital) exports data to excel. the actual spreadsheet is several thousand rows.
for each patient it creates a row for each drug they are on. so if they are not on drugs there isnt a row. if they are on 1 there is one row. if two drugs 2 rows. each row has their id number the name of the drug and the dose in text. we are looking for patients who only take their drugs once a day. they can be on twenty as long as all are od. if even one drug is not od - we are excluding them. so i want a list of every pt who is only on od drugs. the real spreadsheet has other columns. inc tel number. which disease register they are on. etc that we want to preserve. i think... my example is the right answer.

Comment: plz, verify your result; It seems there is no relation to `just show patients who are only on drugs that have a dose of od`.

Comment: each pt has a unique id. the computer system outputs the data this way into excel. each column is patient ID, Drug name, and dosing instructions in text. Im after knowing which patients are only on once a day drugs e.g. od. the problem is each patient can be on more than one drug. so its ok if all there drugs are od. but not if one of theirs is. ok the answer might be 1 and 3 however there are other columns. which i need to preserve. so column 4 might be telephone number. so i dont just want the answer 1 and 3. i want the rows that meet the criteria. including the other data in those rows.

Comment: Do you need a list of patients ID and drug name with `od` dose at all ?

Comment: in column 4 which i didnt show is address. we want to write to all patients who are only on od drugs and invite them into a trial. we dont want to write to anyone who is on a drug that isnt od. the mailing software we have will take the data from column 4 and post them a letter. actually thinking about it - what we really need is ID and column 4.

Comment: for those pts that match the criteria. so the real out put would be id 1 - address - 3 - address

Comment: I add an answer but it needs another column that I add it as `d`, change it to your own,  I hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add A column to your sheet: `[@isOd]` od `d`

```
=IF([@dose]="od"; 0; 1)
or
=IF(A2="od"; 0; 1)
```

result : `[isAllOd]`

```
=IF(SUMIF(Table1[[Id]:[isOd]];[@Id];Table1[[isOd]:[isOd]]) = 0; True; False)
or
=IF(SUMIF(A:D;A2;D:D)= 0; TRUE; FALSE)
```

Comment: You can filter `IsAllOd` by `True` value.

Comment: i can get what you are doing here but it doesnt work for me. have i got the syntax wrong. im putting =IF(SUMIF(A2:D2,A2,D2:D2)=0,TRUE,FALSE) into the top column and copying it down so it updates for each row?

Comment: actually it works if i use =IF(SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,A2,$D$2:$D$10)=0,TRUE,FALSE) and filter for True.

Comment: And `=IF(SUMIF($A:$A,A2,$D:$D)=0,TRUE,FALSE) ` is a better one